# Count matches between two columns on Google Docs

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I have two columns that I want to test if any of their values matches and count how much of them. For example:

```
1  2
2  5
3  1
4  7
```

Should return two, since 1 and 2 are in both columns.
I've found that in excel I could do `=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A4=B1:B4)`, but I can't find the same in Google Spreadsheet. I tried `=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMPRODUCT(A1:A4=B1:B4))`, but it didn't work.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I think its strange to answer your own question, but since I found the solution..

I archieved it doing `=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(COUNTIF(A1:A4=B1:B4)))`

Comment: Sounds good ... we are looking for a similar formula where position 1 in the range is compared to position 1 in the other range etc

Comment: Assume your Column A is `A, B, C`, and Column B is `A, B, B`. You command does not work in comparing textual differences. How can you count the matches of textual differences?

Comment: Just a correction on Countif, it is `,` instead of `=`
`=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(COUNTIF(A1:A4, B1:B4)))`